# Escaping characters in Azure Devops Library variables

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When using Azure Devops Pipelines to release a web application with variable substitution enabled, how can I disable escaping special characters?

I am using the [File Transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops) task by Microsoft. Task information: (1) file format = JSON; (2) target files = **/appsettings.json.

E.g. I want to replace value in appsettings.json with a variable from Library. But when library variable contains special characters, e.g. `password\"`, it will get escaped and the value in appsettings becomes `password\\\"`.

What do I need to do to get the value `password\"` substituted into my appsettings?

Comment: This might be related to the replacement function trying to create valid json before replacing. I just confirmed that the the variable outputs literally with no transformation. What task are you using for replacement? Can you share the appsettings and task information?

Comment: I am using the [File Transform task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops) by Microsoft. Task information has only 2 values: (1) file format = JSON; (2) target files = **/appsettings.json.

Comment: When the escaped value is deserialized, does it not output the original value? It won't be able to deserialize incorrect JSON. For instance, `"password": "password\""` would deserialize as `password"`. It seems to me that what it serialized to is correct and should work.

Comment: Nope, I just tested it. Added ```"password": "password\""``` in appsettings.json. Calling ```configuration.GetSection("password").Value``` then returns ```"password\""```.

Comment: That looks like it's _not_ escaping the values then, right? Your original post said that `password\\\"` was being returned. Do you just not want the quotes around it?

Comment: You have a point! I just got too lost & confused and thought the ```\``` is part of the password, which it is not.. Took me 3 days to wrap my head around it, thank you!